# UILabel is not updating it's text, IOS

Tags: ios, uilabel

I am stuck at a simple task, I have uilabel on my uiviewcontroller's interface file. I want to update that label via some methods. It doesn't update the label.

[image]

```
.h
UIViewController
{
  UILabel *pictureNameLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *pictureNameLabel;

.m
@synthesize pictureNameLabel=_pictureNameLabel;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        _pictureNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _pictureNameLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        _pictureNameLabel.text=@"Try";
}
```

How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to alloc the label. It's already alive and get's awaken from the nib.

```
.h
UIViewController
{
  //UILabel *pictureNameLabel;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *pictureNameLabel;

.m
@synthesize pictureNameLabel=_pictureNameLabel;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
        //_pictureNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _pictureNameLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        _pictureNameLabel.text=@"Try";
}
```

Comment: Not only do you not need it but you are actually pointing to a new label that is not actually on screen (not with allocing, that is just wasting memory, but in re-assigning your pointer to the label) and then updating that. You broke the connection to your outlet.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I alloc UIWebview like the same way and it works What is the difference between them, how can I determine that a UI element needs to be allocated or not?

Comment: you only alloc UI elements when they haven't been added to a nib, and you want to programatically load them to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Your direct problem is the line:

```
_pictureNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
```

In `-ViewDidLoad`. It's creating a *new* variable, and having the `pictureNameLabel` property point to it, causing you to lose your reference to the one created in Interface Builder. Remove that line, and everything should work fine.

If you've created an element via Interface Builder, you do not need to alloc & init it yourself, along with adding it to the view in the appropriate spot, as it's automatically done for you, and the property is already set to point to it. If you're manually creating a new view, you do need to do that... but you'd also need to add it somewhere in the view hierarchy as a subview.

Not related to your problem, but you have also created a variable named `UILabel *pictureNameLabel;`. I'd assume you created this variable to be the backing variable for the synthesized property `pictureNameLabel`... but, you synthesized that to `_pictureNameLabel`, which means you now have two variables, `_pictureNameLabel` and `pictureNameLabel`. This is almost certainly a mistake. You should either remove the manual definition of `pictureNameLabel`, or rename it to something distinct if you actually intend to use it separately from the property with the same name. Having it is likely to just lead to confusion & bugs down the road.

Comment: Good explanation I think, as you said, he needs to remove that variable and read more about this topic http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/ios-development-guide-part1/

Answer (score -1):

your label has already exists on your xib file, and you can set the textcolor, text on interface bulider.

Comment: I know that I want to update label's text with various actions